# regresio line didn't display correctly

Tags: r, plot

```
 lab <- data.frame( Month = c("2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-06-01"), AccNumber = c(5683,5418,6001,6184,6001,6184), OCTAT = c(40.20,50.52,47.15,45.03,47.15,45.03), Default = c(30,30,30,30,30,30))

 id <- rownames(lab)
 lab <- cbind(id = id, lab)
 max <- max(lab$AccNumber)
 max2 <- max(lab$OCTAT)
 p <- barplot(lab$AccNumber, names.arg = lab$Month, xlab = "Month", col = "blue" ,ylim = c(0, max + 2000))
 par(new=TRUE)
 plot(x = id, y = lab$OCTAT, type = "l", col = "red", axes = FALSE, ylim = c(0, 60), ann = FALSE)
 plot(x = id, y = lab$OCTAT, type = "l", col = "green", axes = FALSE, ylim = c(0, 60), ann = FALSE, lwd = 2)
 p <- barplot(lab$AccNumber, names.arg = lab$Month, xlab = "Month", col = "blue" ,ylim = c(0, max + 2000))
 par(new=TRUE)
 plot(x = id, y = lab$OCTAT, type = "l", col = "green", axes = FALSE, ylim = c(0, 60), ann = FALSE, lwd = 2)
 axis(4, at=seq(0, max2 + 10, 10))
 abline(h = 30, lwd = 2)  # Default blue line (30)
 abline(lm(lab$OCTAT ~ lab$id), col = "red", lty = 2) #Regression line trend
```

After running the code this is what I got below. I am totally new to R. How can I get a regression line that look like the second pic.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dashed red line to span from the left axis to the right axis, change the last line of code to:

```
abline(lm(lab$OCTAT ~ as.numeric(lab$id)), col = "red", lty = 2)
```

This is because `lab$id` is of class character.

If you want the red dashed line to span the same width as the green line, change the last line of code to:

```
lines(x = c(1,6), y = c(44.9953, 46.6983), col = 'red', lty = 2)
```

The values 44.9953 and 46.6983 are obtained from putting id = 1 and id = 6 into the model fitted from `lm(lab$OCTAT ~ as.numeric(lab$id)`.

Hope this is what you were looking for.